# SUM up 4 measures in SSAS

Tags: ssas

I want to sum up 4 measures in SSAS and divide the total by 1 measure
my code is as follows.

```
=Sum((Fields!Unique_Visits.Value)+Sum(Fields!Ask_the_Expert.Value)
+Sum(Fields!SSMembers.Value)+Sum(Fields!Poll_Members.Value))/
Sum(Fields!EnrolledMembers.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your measures are defined as using the SUM aggregate function (which is the default) then Analysis Services will do the summing for you and you just need to add the measures together and do the division

([Measures].[Unique Visits] + [Measures].[Ask the Expert] + [Measures].[SSMembers] + [Measures].[Poll_Members] ) / [Measures].[Enrolled Members]